# Who can review the new topic when created for documentation?

Tags: support, documentation

When we create a new topic for documentation, it's not visible for until it's reviewed. Who review these topics and what is criteria for reviewing?

Comment: I seemingly have a review priviledge but I can't do anything anywhere.

Comment: Does the review Privilege for Documentation and Edit of Q&A is different ?

Comment: I was wondering that myself. It would be good to have like 10 users with highest rep in a specific tag, who can review these documentations. Also it would be good if we select people who are active on SO and have high reputation. Just a thought.

Comment: Same as @Vladimir - clicking "Review" when I'm on the documentation site just takes me to the normal SO review queue.

Comment: Wait I just discovered: if you go to a particular topic and scroll down, on the right there may be "N Proposed Changes" and a "Review" button next to them. That's probably it.

Comment: @whrrgarbl  have a look on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328893/how-to-review-in-documentation-site

Comment: It has been 8 hours since I submitted a new topic. It is still pending review!

Answer (score 3):

The [Documentation Review Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-reviewing) help page has this info:

> Awarded At: 100 Reputation
>
> **What is documentation reviewing?**
>
> Whenever a change is proposed in Documentation - be it an addition, an
>   edit, or a delete - it goes into a queue. Other members of the
>   community review these proposed changes before they take effect.
>
> Once enough reviews are accrued, the change is either approved and put
>   into effect or rejected.