# How to review in the documentation site

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, documentation, documentation-topics

I have been searching for review buttons for the new beta Documentation. I can't find them under the review section, and this is why I have created this post.

I hope the post will be helpful.

Comment: Thank christ someone asked this, I have been trying to find this for ages. As with a lot of the "documentation" the UI for me, is complicated and confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Review button for `proposed changes`

Click on Javascript Language Tag
[image]

Click on proposed changes link

[image]

Click on review
[image]

You will see `Approve` | `Reject` buttons.

**2.** Dismiss button for requested topic 
[image]

**3.** If you like some requested topic, you can upvote it, visiting tag-> requests click upvote arrow
[image]
[image]